# Recalculating Apex Managed Sharing

Tags: apex, sharing, apex-managed-sharing

I am studying "Apex Managed Sharing" but I have a problem with "Recalculating Apex Managed Sharing".

The [`Apex Developer Guide`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_recalc.htm) says:

> Every time a custom object's organization-wide sharing default access
>   level is updated, any Apex recalculation classes defined for
>   associated custom object are also executed.

I have created an Apex Class implementing `Database.Batch` interface and I have assigned this class for my Custom Object.

If I start the Recalculation from UI the code run correctly but if I change OWD the code is not executed.

Comment: update OWD from Public Read Only or Public Read Write to Private, and check what happens

Comment: Please always link to any resource you cite in your posts. That said, I think the documentation is just wrong here. Not sure how they would tell which batches should even execute unless there were a separate interface.

Comment: @SantanuBoral I have done these test but nothing has happened

Comment: @AdrianLarson, the documentation he linked to shows how to "associate an Apex managed sharing recalculation class with a custom object" all the way at the bottom.

Comment: @DanielHoechst and therein lies the likely answer. That step seems almost certainly missed here.

Answer (score 2):

To associate an Apex managed sharing recalculation class with a custom object:

1. From the management settings for the custom object, go to Apex Sharing Recalculations.
2. Choose the Apex class that recalculates the Apex sharing for this object. The class you choose must implement the Database.Batchable interface. You cannot associate the same Apex class multiple times with the same custom object.
3. Click Save.

To run an Apex sharing recalculation, from the management settings for a custom object, go to Apex Sharing Recalculation, and then click New.

When working with Apex sharing recalculations, note the following.

1. The Apex code that extends the sharing recalculation can process a maximum of five million records. If thisApex code affects more than five million records, the job fails immediately.
2. You can monitor the status of Apex sharing recalculations in the Apex job queue.
3. You can associate a maximum of five Apex sharing recalculations per custom object.
4. You cannot associate Apex sharing recalculations with standard objects.

Comment: I can't see apex sharing recalculation in the object settings , my custom object is set to private

Answer (score 0):

I think I finnaly found the solution, you will only be able to see the apex sharing reasons and apex sharing Recalcultation categories if you **switch to classic** and navigate to your object in setup.

[image]